# Scheduling a job with Postgresql for non-admin user

Tags: postgresql, scheduler

Is there a tool that will allow me to schedule Postgresql queries to run at regular intervals without being an Admin? I'm looking for solutions that would work on a Mac.

I only have write privileges (insert, update, delete) on certain schemas of the database but would like to schedule a query that runs on one of these schemas every day.

pgAgent is the obvious choice but I think I need to be an admin to use/install that.

Comment: could the scheduling be done via cron or launchd? cron still works on mac os although deprecated. launchd is the recommended method going forward

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a tool that will allow me to schedule Postgresql queries to run at regular intervals without being an Admin? I'm looking for solutions that would work on a Mac.

Use [`pg_cron`](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron)

```
INSERT INTO cron.job (schedule, command, nodename, nodeport, database, username)
VALUES ('0 4 * * *', 'VACUUM', 'worker-node-1', 5432, 'postgres', 'marco');
```

this requires you to install the extension as an admin.

You can also run `crontab -e` assuming it's supported by OSX. If you want to, as a regular user, set up a task to run (even non-DB tasks).